# Animate between positions with just CSS?

Tags: javascript, animation, css, css-transitions

I want to animate between "default" states/positions for a div. For example:

Div **absolutely** positioned with a class, to be on the *left* of the screen. Class is removed via JS (or replaced) and position is now **relative**. The default relative position is actually on the opposite side of the screen. I want to animate this.

Something like a dock, various divs as icons in display-inline, centered horizontally on the dock. If I "delete" one of the icons, the rest will shift a bit to recenter. I want to animate them shifting to fill the gap.

Transition: all does not work (I assume because there was no predefined values for the position) so is this even possible? Are there JS solutions to this?

Comment: Possible but why do you want to reinvent the wheel? Use frameworks. Something similar to what you are looking - http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/dd/list-drag.html

Comment: Just FYI, here a list of [the CSS animatable properties](http://oli.jp/2010/css-animatable-properties/).

Comment: @Calvein and all-in-one as examples: http://leaverou.github.com/animatable/

Answer (score 3):

It's possible exactly the way you described it. Here's a live example of how it's done.

http://jsfiddle.net/nDr4y/3/

You can also remove the transition from css and use [jquery to animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) the element with pure JS. The syntax looks like this:

```
// in the object are the css properties you want to animate,
// the second argument is how long you want it to take in ms
$('.el').animate({ left: 100 }, 1000);
```

Comment: I should probably reword it, but the first example is specifically tied to the position absolute -> position relative change. I know how to use transitions normally. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I updated the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/nDr4y/3/ - the absolute > relative shouldn't make a difference. If I were to guess on what's getting you hung up here it would be that you are looking to animate the overall position of the element rather than a single property. The position can be influenced by a number of properties, but to have the css transition work you need to animate just one single css property.

Comment: Ok, so the position property isn't the issue, my main problem would be to somehow know the x/y coordinates beforehand. I just kinda wished there was a way the CSS could animate between the left/top defaults that change by switching from absolute -> relative. :( Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I see what you're getting at now. This is definitely not possible with css animations (the nature is that they animate a property, not figure out the position and animate that), but can certainly be done with javascript. Do you want an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to figure out the destination coordinates and set it using jQuery, or whatever framework you use. Other than that, it's totally possible.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kd72u/